# How to add gltf model in threejs?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am searching for a method, how to add this model to my page. Cuz now, I have only a black bottle without any glare. When i uploaded this model, i cant add color and e.t to the bottle. Ive added some code after.   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhLpV.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIAeg.jpg

```js
     var camera, scene, renderer;

            init();

            function init() {

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 100);
                directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                scene.add(directionalLight);
                 scene.add(light4);

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
                camera.position.x = 1;
                camera.position.y = 1.5;
                camera.position.z = 2;
                scene.add(camera);

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    antialias: true
                });
                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
                loader.load('../ws_r_2-3.glb', function(gltf) {
                    gltf.scene.position.y = 0;
                    scene.add(gltf.scene);
                    render();
                });
                 
                var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                controls.addEventListener('change', render);
                controls.update();

                window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            }

            function onWindowResize() {


                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render(scene, camera);

            }
```

Comment: Consider to share your entire code as a live example or GitHub repo.

Comment: http://weblife.su/WineBazar/1/

Comment: The intensity of your `DirectionalLight` is way too high. Right now, it is `100`. Change it to `1`. Besides, try to apply an environment map to `Scene.environment` like in the official glTF example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf since the materials of your model have a metalness value of `1`.

Comment: Can i add opaciy to my bottle? I have a good result in Blender